# Initialization in the for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

can someone explain the what the initialize part doing? and how this for loop going to end?

```
 The for loop generally I see is 
  for(int i =0; i<5; i++){

 }


but the following one is 
 int[][] xx = { {-1,0},  {0,1},{1,0},{0,-1}};


 for(int[] y : xx){
    int i = y[0];
    int j = y[1];


    System.out.println(i+" "+j);
 }
```

Comment: Time to read about the [enhanced for statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: This is an understandable question. After all, it's not as though there's ubiquitous documentation explaining how Java features work and including examples. Oh, wait...

Comment: The answer is the first link when you type "Colon in for loop, Java" into Google. Do some research before asking stuff on SO. Otherwise you're just wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an *enhanced for loop*. This:

```
for(int[] y : xx){
    . . .
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
for (int index = 0; index < xx.length; ++index) {
    int[] y = xx[index];
    . . .
}
```

where `index` is a compiler-generated variable name that does not occur within the body of the `for` loop.

You can read more about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with).